Why is the compiler suggesting I use a higher ranked lifetime and what even is one?
This function, which accepts a generic type T where T implements IntoIterator and yields an Item of type I that can be derefenced to a string slice, will not compile.
// This will not compile

fn foo<T, I>(input: T)
where
    T: IntoIterator<Item = I>,
    I: Deref<Target = &str>,
{
    for item in input {
        todo!()
    }
}

It seems a relatively straightforward fix, introduce a generic lifetime 'a and add it to the string slice:
// This will compile

fn foo<'a, T, I>(input: T)
where
    T: IntoIterator<Item = I>,
    I: Deref<Target = &'a str>,
{
    for item in input {
        todo!()
    }
}

However this is not the suggested solution from the compiler:
error[E0637]: `&` without an explicit lifetime name cannot be used here
  --> src/main.rs:14:23
   |
14 |     I: Deref<Target = &str>,
   |                       ^ explicit lifetime name needed here
   |
help: consider introducing a higher-ranked lifetime here
   |
14 |     I: for<'a> Deref<Target = &'a str>,
   |   

What is a higher ranked lifetime, do I need to know about them and why is the compiler suggesting I use one?

"why is the compiler suggesting I use one?" - it is a way to introduce a lifetime for a constraint. In this case though, it is almost definitely not what you want.
